# Change Joomla Template parameters

Tags: templates, joomla, parameters

Im developing an e-commerce with Joomla 2.5 using a template which has a slideshow embedded (not a module).

I want to create an article where the client himself can easily upload images and their descriptions and urls for the slideshow.

I've managed to load a file uploader module in an article and it works. But I don't know how to change the descriptions and urls.

The descriptions and urls are template parameters and I don't know how to set them from the article.

The `params.ini` file in template folder is blank.. The .xml shows the 's for them but not their current value.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting two functions to work, but you're missing the whole logic that links images to pages, and assigns them names, possibly manage a little security.

Why do you want to build this from scratch? You'd be so much better off with a ready-made, free, tested and supported CCK (e.g. contentbuilder, k2, sobi, zoo just to name a few).

Comment: I would like to use build it from scratch because the slider comes embedded in the template. My client likes it.

Comment: well, look at the source in your template, most likely it's using a standard js plugin for the slideshow; if however you must proceed this way, I'd say it's better and easier to put the logic for upload and image management in a backend or frontend component, rather than in the template.